# Is it possible to set the lein :main value from the command prompt instead of editing the file?

Tags: command-line, clojure, leiningen

I have a Clojure project with a number of examples I'd like to run with leiningen in a demo standing in front of a group of people.

Now what I could do is set the value of `:main` in the `project.clj` and do `lein run` each time.

```
  :main examples.exj-impressive/example-j
```

But to be honest this doesn't make for a very impressive demo in what is supposed to be a very impressive dynamic language.

What I'd like to do is specify the value of `:main` on the command line each time.

My question is: **Is it possible to set the lein :main value from the command prompt instead of editing the file?**

Comment: Have you considered demoing from a REPL instead of the command line?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is entirely possible to do that using -m parameter.

```
lein run -m  your_namespace/main_function
```

If your function takes paramaters you can pass them too

```
lein run -m your_namespace/main_function "(a list of parameters)"
```

So your exact case would be

```
lein run -m examples.exj-impressive/example-j
```